# platforms in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, gpu

I have Nvidia Graphics card(GeForce GT 640) ON MY MOTHERBOARD.
I have installed OpenCL on my box.
When I query about platform using "clGetPlatformInfo(parameters)", I see the following output:-
`#Available platforms: 1.`
`#1 CL_PLATFORM_NAME: NVIDIA CUDA`
`#1 CL_PLATFORM_PROFILE: FULL_PROFILE`
`#1 CL_PLATFORM_VERSION: OpenCL 1.1 CUDA 4.2.1`
`#1 CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR: NVIDIA Corporation`

What should I infer from the above output?
As per my understanding CUDA and OpenCL are two different platform.
The output says total available platform is:1, platform name is CUDA and version is OpenCL and CUDA. I am to totally confused.

Comment: The fact that `clGetPlatformInfo` queries the properties of an *OpenCL* platform and not some arbitrary unrelated information should be enough to infer that the queried platform actually *is* a valid *OpenCL* platform. In the end platform names and version strings can be completely arbitrary and in this case it just means that this platform is *somehow related* to *CUDA* (in this case bundled with and implemented by).

Answer (score 5):

NVIDIA's OpenCL platform is bundled with the CUDA toolkit, not to be confused with the CUDA programming language. You have version 4.2.1 of the CUDA toolkit which contains OpenCL 1.1. You can have more than one OpenCL platforms installed (Intel and AMD has their own platforms).